# how do for scanf ints without line feed in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am a beginner in the C language, and I wanted to know if there is a method to put a variable in a "scanf" without going to line by typing "enter" in the console.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE_MAX 256
#define END_INPUT -1

int main() {
  int tab[SIZE_MAX], size;
  int i;

  /* Saisie du tableau de départ */
  printf("Enter the different elements of the table\n");
  printf("(%d to end)\n", END_INPUT);

  for (size = 0; size < SIZE_MAX; size = size + 1) {
    scanf("%d", &tab[size]);
    if (tab[size] == END_INPUT) {
      break;
    }
  }
  printf("Tableau de size %d :\n", size);
  i = size;

  while (i >= 0) {
    if (tab[size - i] == END_INPUT) {
      printf("\n");
      break;
    }
    printf("%d ", tab[size - i]);
    i--;
  }

  /* Displaying the table */
  return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzZ5A.png)

to this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbcTb.png)

Comment: The `%d` format reads any *white-space* separated integer. Newline is a white-space, as is normal space and tab. So the user can write all the input in a single line, with only spaces between the numbers, and only press the `Enter` key once all numbers are written. Your program would not know the difference.

Comment: As @Someprogrammerdude says, typing more than one number on the same line will just work. But you cannot avoid having to type ENTER after the -1, because no part of a line is read until the user indicates that the line is done by typing ENTER. (There's a lot of oversimplification in that comment but it will serve your needs.)

Comment: Redwan Khan, As you type `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, etc.  How do you way to indicate the typing of digits is done if not by a `'\n'`?  By typing a space? a non-digit? some signal?

Comment: And: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Copy&paste the output *as text*.